# How to get the SafeAreaLayoutGuide for the ViewControllers of a UITabBarController?

Tags: c#, ios, swift, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I'm trying to set the `Anchors` of a View, in order to stay below the status bar, using:

```
UILayoutGuide safeGuide = view.Superview.SafeAreaLayoutGuide;
view.TranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false;
view.LeadingAnchor.ConstraintEqualTo(safeGuide.LeadingAnchor).Active = true;
view.TrailingAnchor.ConstraintEqualTo(safeGuide.TrailingAnchor).Active = true;
view.TopAnchor.ConstraintEqualTo(safeGuide.TopAnchor).Active = true;
view.BottomAnchor.ConstraintEqualTo(safeGuide.BottomAnchor).Active = true;
```

But I'm getting the View partially obscured by the tabs on the bottom of the `UITabBarController`.

How do I avoid that?

Comment: *`view.Superview.SafeAreaLayoutGuide;`* doesn't look right... in your code, is `view` the "root" view of a controller embedded in a TabBarController?

Comment: @DonMag The View is the root view of a `UIViewController` which is one of the `UITabBarController`'s `ViewControllers`.

Comment: @DonMag It's proving _very_ hard to achieve so ever so simple job of showing the View of said UIViewController below the status bar, but still above the tabs of the UITabBarController.

Comment: ok -  you shouldn't be using `view.TranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false;` In fact, you shouldn't need to do *any* of that.

Comment: @DonMag OK. I'll be happy to know how I can avoid that. How? (Just leaving it all out, shows part of the View behind the status bar.)

Comment: The root view of a controller is always overlaid by the status bar. That view's `SafeAreaLayoutGuide` is what you use to prevent added **subviews** from extending into the status bar area.

Comment: @DonMag Thanks! You can post that as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The root view of a controller is always overlaid by the status bar.

That view's `SafeAreaLayoutGuide` is what you use to prevent ***added subviews*** from extending into the status bar area.

This is true whether you are using a `UITabBarController`, a `UINavigationController`, a regular `UIViewController`, etc.